# Gmail text highlighting bug in Safari

Tags: macos, gmail, safari, gui

I have a simple problem. As a Gmail user, I often like to drag tags from the left sidebar and drop them on individual conversations in my inbox.

Quite recently, I started encountering something that can be described only as UI bug in the web app - when I click on and start dragging a tag with my mouse cursor, portions of the website's text get highlighted and unhighlighted, flickering with every mouse move. It's very disturbing and I would do anything to get rid of it.

Does anybody have a suggestion how to resolve this? I'm using Safari 9.0.3.

Thanks in advance,
Pete.

Comment: This could either be an issue with your browser (like you said a UI bug) or more likely a programming error. If this is the case, there is nothing you can do as an end user. It sounds like it could also be simply poor design and you _could_ possibly not be dragging the actual button but instead a piece of styling around it. When you get the highlighting, that simply means your clicking something that is not recognized as a button but rather text. TL;DR: It could be an issue but there is nothing as an end user that you can do.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought so. My only hope is that somebody from Gmail stumbles across this and  manages to fix it in my lifetime. :)